# Dirt 3 doesn't launch on windows 7 64-bit

Tags: dirt-3

I recently installed dirt3 but it doesn't start (nothing happens when i double click the icon) my pc have i5 processor , 6 GB Ram , nvidia 610M-2GB .

Answer (score 0):

Dirt 3 isn't supported by Codemasters anymore.

You can [redeem the serial code on Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352) to get the [Dirt 3 Complete Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/321040/?l=turkish) which includes all DLCs and is optimized for newer OSes for free.

See the announcement [here](https://steamcommunity.com/games/321040/announcements/detail/133195170799950347).

> if you own a boxed PC copy of DiRT 3 or have a Games For Windows Live CD Key you can now activate that CD key on Steam.